# How to commit a resource once but not future changes to it in git?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way to commit a file once so it is in the repository but then not commit that file in the future?

For example, I have a project that I need to commit once so another developer can import the project but I do not want to commit that file again because local path changes mess up his copy of it when he pulls the file down.

I'd like to use `SourceTree` for working with `git` but an answer with `git` commands will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First commit the initial version of the file. Then just run

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged FILENAME
```

This will make it so that git will ignore future changes you make to `FILENAME`. If in the future, you need to commit something again, run

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged FILENAME
```

Note that this only applies to your working copy. Anyone else who checks out the repository will still have git see their changes unless they also run the command above.

Comment: That worked. I didn't find an equivalent option in SourceTree so I ran it on the command line and SourceTree handled it as if it had no changes.